# How to set affinity on multi-socket system (2 CPUs)

Tags: affinity

I have a machine with two six-core processors (hyper-threading turned off).  I understand how to set the affinity for a program using the command line when there is only one processor, but how do you do it for 2 CPUs?  Do I just treat it as if I have a single 12-core processor?  Or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: What options are displayed when you try to change the affinity in Task Manager? What tool / option are you using to set it via the command line, and what does the documentation for that tool say?

Comment: Please also indicate which operating system and version you are running, in addition to the info Darth Android asked of you.

Comment: Sorry, this is on Windows 7.  I am using the command line in a shortcut link to set the affinity.  When I look at processor affinity, I see CPU0 Node 0,1,2,3,4,5 and CPU1 Node 0,1,2,3,4,5.